# Making a Number Picker from Scratch that Starts at 100 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make number picker from scratch that starts at 100 and goes up and down in increments of 2.5. This is for a max bench press project I am working on. I just started really programming in general this week. I had the app up and running, but decided that I hated the layout, so I started over. I just can't get the weight to go up or down by 2.5 every time I press the buttons. It will go up or down once, but not multiple times. Please help me.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Button Calculate;
private Button plus;
private Button menus;
private OnClickListener buttonclick;
private TextView textView;
double weight;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    menus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    menus.setOnClickListener(this);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    Calculate.setOnClickListener(this);


    double weight = 100;
    textView.setText("" + String.valueOf(weight));




}

public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:
        textView.setText("" + String.valueOf(weight + 2.5));
        weight = weight + 2.5;
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        textView.setText("" + String.valueOf(weight - 2.5));
        weight = weight - 2.5;
        break;
    case R.id.button:


        break;
}

}
```

}

Comment: Why no tuse a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'double' from this line: `double weight = 100;`